# Off-Topic Question Clarification

Tags: discussion

My question is around questions like this:

[How do Telco's reduce your network speed?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45056/how-do-telcos-reduce-your-network-speed)

I completely agree that questions about networks outside of our control should be off-topic.  In the linked question, OP is not referencing a specific network, if he had asked "How does AT&T reduce network speed?" - I would say it's totally off-topic.

He's obviously asking about QoS or similar technologies but doesn't have all of the context, I think anyone here can infer that.  Part of learning is getting past the "known unknowns".

I think it's our responsibility in cases like this one to help them out a bit and encourage an edit to the question to make it on-topic, or like other questions reference him to another SE (QoS stuff would belong to us in this case).

Comment: Personally, I would have closed the question as a duplicate because we already have a couple of such answered questions.

Comment: And I think that is a totally acceptable alternative as we tend to link the other question.  I think anything that could have given OP more context to find his explicit answer is what I was getting at.